# How to find if values in two adjacent cells match to two adjacent cell values in 2 different columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

The idea is to find if the two adjacent cell values in c2 and d2 match to any two adjacent cells in column a and column b.

[image: Matching 2 adjacent cells to 2 adjacent cells in 2 different columns]

I'm thinking some form of vlookup, index and/or iferror will work but I haven't found the answer yet; obviously.

Thanks in advance for anyone's help.

Comment: I didn't think of the concat idea - that approach certainly works. The VBA script works and is a little less hands on. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw this into VBA and it'll get the job done:

```
Public Sub Match()

Dim k As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String

application.calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

i = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1

For j = 1 To i
    str1 = Range("C1").Offset(j, 0)
    str2 = CStr(Range("D1").Offset(j, 0))
    For k = 1 To i
        If Range("A1").Offset(k, 0).Value = str1 And Range("B1").Offset(k, 0).Value = str2 Then
            Range("E1").Offset(j, 0).Value = "y"
            GoTo Spot
        End If
        Range("E1").Offset(j, 0).Value = "n"
    Next
Spot:
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
application.calculation = xlCalculationautomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: This works too - super cool Blake! Going to give you the win on this one!

Comment: Thanks! I edited it a little haha. It'll run faster now in case you're dealing with a lot of data and the "n" will show up now, thought I threw that in there before ;)

Comment: Dudeee I was going to say i would love for it to both run faster (it actually broke my spreadsheet and had to restart - running on about 100k rows) and to have 'n' included instead of '' but I didn't want to be annoying.

Comment: Haha, that's awesome xD. 100k rows is a ton, this code might still crash your excel sheet :o. Let me know your results! It might take a few minutes to run but it might take even longer than that I'm not really sure haha. If it's too slow don't hesitate to ask me to make some changes! I got one more idea I could try. Also if you save your file as an xlsb (binary) the code tends to run a little faster. 

Also I made one small change, if you have calculations on your sheet the change I made will save A LOT of time. I'm interested to hear how it goes, let me know please!

Answer (score 1):

Create a column C have this be =A1 & "|" & B1
now since the rest of the sheet is moved over by 1 cell
Create a column in F have this be =D1 & "|" & E1

Do your vlookup on C and F and put in G.

I used the "|" because you don't want to smash them together. You may get false matches.

Comment: Did just that and "=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(F2,C:C,0),"yes",),"no")" worked in column h

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare concatenated data.  This can be done in two ways:

1. Concatenate in the formula - for Cell `E2`

   ```
   =MATCH(C2 & "_" & D2, A1:A100 & "_" & B1:B100,0)
   ```

   Use a character to seperate the columns that does not otherwise appear in the data.
   Enter as an Array Formula (Complete with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
   Adjust the match range (rows 1 to 100 in my example) to suit your data.  Note that whole columns are not recommended for array formula's)
2. Add a helper column, say `F:F` with formula (for `F2`), and copy down

   ```
   =C2 & "_" & D2
   ```

   Then formula in `E2` becomes (standard formula)

   ```
   =MATCH(C2&"_"&D2,F:F,0)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You could also do this. I made 2 columns to concatenate (tie together) the adjacent cells which made using the index/match method a possible.

The formulas are as follows:

Column C: `=CONCATENATE(A2,B2)`

Column F: `=CONCATENATE(D2,E2)`

Column G: `=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(C2:C6,MATCH(F2,C2:C6,0)))=TRUE,"n","y")`

Hope this helps